# Installing Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 - Setting up repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, docker

I am trying to install docker on Ubuntu 16.04. I am a complete Ubuntu newbie and only installed it recently.

Here are the installation steps: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/

In order to setup the directory, I have to run this command:

```
bash $ sudo apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \ curl \ apt-transport-https \ ca-certificates \ curl \ software-properties-common
```

I am quite confused on what to copy and paste exactly. 
I first copied and pasted everything from sudo:

```
sudo apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \ curl \ apt-transport-https \ ca-certificates \ curl \ software-properties-common
```

But I get the following errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package curl 
E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https 
E: Unable to locate package ca-certificates 
E: Unable to locate package curl 
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

Do you know what those erros mean and what can I do to install Docker properly?

Thank you.

Comment: thank you for your answer, sorry I forgot to mention that I tried that, as a result I get: 'bash: $: No such file or directory

Comment: Would it be okey to just install it without adding the repository?

Comment: how would I install it without the repo? and it is clearly mentionned that you need to setup the directory

Comment: The [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) is not the only way to install the program, its handy and simple  for later updates though. You can install it following [this instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command you entered is mostly correct, however, it suffers from a flaw: those `\` are supposed to escape newlines, *not* spaces. The command in the docs is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common
```

This should be copy-pasted as-is (except the leading `$`) or typed in similarly. By removing the newlines, this is what happened:

```
$ printf "|%s|\n" sudo apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \ curl \ apt-transport-https \ ca-certificates \ curl \ software-properties-common
|sudo|
|apt-get|
|-y|
|--no-install-recommends|
|install|
| curl|
| apt-transport-https|
| ca-certificates|
| curl|
| software-properties-common|
```

As you can see, the spaces became part of the package names. That is why `apt-get` couldn't find them. Do either of:

```
sudo apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install curl apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
  curl \
  apt-transport-https \
  ca-certificates \
  software-properties-common
```

Comment: @user2505650 - I think you should have accepted this answer, not mine. Mine may work, but this one answers exactly and more precisely what you came asking in the first place :)

Answer (score 5):

### Installation from a .deb package

If you cannot use Docker’s repository to install Docker, you can download the .deb file for your release and install it manually. You will need to download a new file each time you want to upgrade Docker.

- Go to https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/pool/main/d/docker-engine/ and download the .deb file for the Docker version you want to install and for your version of Ubuntu ([latest version 1.13.1 for Ubuntu 16.04](https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/pool/main/d/docker-engine/docker-engine_1.13.1-0~ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb)).
- Install Docker, changing the path below to the path where you downloaded the Docker package.

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb
  ```

  The Docker daemon starts automatically.
- Verify that docker is installed correctly by running the hello-world image.

  ```
  sudo docker run hello-world
  ```

  This command downloads a test image and runs it in a container. When the container runs, it prints an informational message and exits.

Docker is installed and running. You need to use `sudo` to run Docker commands.

---

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package

Answer (score 3):

Although you can set up the repo and install it manually, there is a faster way using the official [convenience script](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#upgrade-docker-ce-1).

As of 2018, to install `docker-ce` on Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 18.04, the command for the automated install is:

```
curl https://get.docker.com | sudo sh
```

Read the security note printed in output toward the end of the install. Note that the script at the URL used above is maintained in the [docker-install](https://github.com/docker/docker-install/) repo.

This installs the package and the repo. To confirm:

```
$ apt list docker-ce* 2>&- | grep installed
docker-ce/now 5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-xenial amd64 [installed,local]
docker-ce-cli/now 5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-xenial amd64 [installed,local]
```

Verify installation:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
sudo docker version
```

Continue with [post-installation steps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/).

Comment: Where did you find this? The official installation instructions (as well as the other sites that talk about docker installation) are way too long, and this script is easy. Should be prominently mentioned in the official docker install instructions [instead of all this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)

Comment: @DannyB I had linked to the [docker-install](https://github.com/docker/docker-install) repo in my answer. Also see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31514

Comment: Thanks for this. I hope they opt to update the get.docker.com install script rather than deprecate it, I hate the multi-step installation, and apparently I am [not the only one](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31514#issuecomment-302599245).

Answer (score 1):

The Docker installation package available in the official Ubuntu  repositories may not be the latest version. So I would not suggest to install docker from Ubuntu repositories. To get the latest version,  install Docker from the official Docker repository.

For doing this first of all we will add , the GPG key for the official Docker repository to our machine by `curl` command

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now we will add  the Docker repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

Update the package database with the Docker packages from the newly added repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, install Docker by `apt-get` command

```
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

Docker should now be installed and running. To check whether docker service has been started or not we should run the command `sudo service docker status`. This will show the status of docker service.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common gnupg2
```

Comment: How is this command different from other existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install on a current Ubuntu, you can simply install the `docker.io` package via package manager or

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```